# Symfony2 create Entity from Request

Tags: api, rest, symfony, doctrine, entity

I'm whondering, wheather there is an easy way to pupolate doctrine entities from request objects. I'm building a RESTful API with fos/rest-bundle, so I dont need forms.

Do you know a good way to do this, in a very easy and short way?

```
// POST /api/products
public function postProductsAction(Request $request)
{
    $product = new Product(); 
}
```

In addition, I'm whondering wheather its possible to inject instances of entities directly in the controller with post requests.

```
// PUT /api/product/1
// I need this functionality for post requests too
public function putProductAction(Product $product)
{
    return $product; // { "id" : "1", "name" : "foo" } 
}
```

Greetings,

--marc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is the most common goal of every REST API. And the best way to do this is to use a serializer, in addition to forms (even if you would prefere to not use forms).

I advise you to read for example [this tutorial writen by William Durand](http://williamdurand.fr/2012/08/02/rest-apis-with-symfony2-the-right-way/). It explains every points very well and uses the [JMSSerializerBundle](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSSerializerBundle) to convert entities through the API.

Comment: I know this is an old post, but I would like to clarify this for people arriving here by search. In the tutorial you mention, forms are still used to transform request into entity / validating. Serializing is only used for the other way around: entity to response.